# How to set 2015-01-20 as Jan 15

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a date that I want to display in SQL Server like this:

```
 Date=`2015-12-08`

 O/p=Dec 15(I need output like this)
```

How can I do it? I tried like

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()), 3) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS [Mon YYYY]`
```

But it returns output like `Dec 2015` but I need it to be `Dec 15`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, GetDate(),6),6)
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(4), GETDATE(), 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), GETDATE(), 120)
```

update :

Your can try if you want only jan 15

```
    SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, "yourdate",6),6)
```

Comment: Still `Dec 2015` I want like Dec 15

Comment: Edited my answer please have a look :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT LEFT(CAST(Date as varchar(20)), 3) + '-' + RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(Date) as CHAR(4)), 2) as MonYr
```

FROM YourTable